# Probability that $U_1 \geq U$, $U_2 \geq U$, $U_3 < U$, $U_4 \geq U$, $U_5 < U$, $U_6 \geq U$, $U_7 \geq U$, for i.i.d. uniform $U_k$s and $U$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, independence

Let $U,U_1,U_2,...$ be independant, on [0,1] uniform distributed random variables.

Let $E$ := {$U_1 \geq U,U_2 \geq U,U_3 < U,U_4 \geq U, U_5 < U,U_6 \geq U,U_7 \geq U$}.

Find the probabiliy $P(E)$ and then find the probability $P(U_8 \geq U |E)$.

---

I am struggling with this task and therefore need help, thanks!

Comment: Where have you got with the first part, finding p(E), which is much easier than the 2nd part? What is $p(U_i<U)$?

Comment: There are two ways of finding $p(U_i<U)$. One is symmetry, the other is to integrate.

Comment: p(E) is the prob of $U_1\ge U$ or $U_2\ge U$ etc. It is easier to calculate the prob of something and something else etc. So you need to calculate the $p(U_1<U\text{ and }U_2<U\text{ and }\dots)$.

Comment: @almagest How's my answer?

Comment: Seeing the horror posted as answer below, here are some hints. For every $u$ in $(0,1)$, let $$E_u := \{U_1 \geq u,U_2 \geq u,U_3 < u,U_4 \geq u, U_5 < u,U_6 \geq u,U_7 \geq u\},$$ then, by independence of $(U_k)$, $$P(E_u)=P(U_1\geq u)^5P(U<u)^2=(1-u)^5u^2,$$ hence, this time because $U$ is independent of $(U_k)$, $$P(E)=\int_0^1P(E_u)du=\int_0^1u^{3-1}(1-u)^{6-1}du=\frac{\Gamma(3)\Gamma(6)}{{}{}\Gamma(9)}=\frac{2!5!}{8!}=\frac1{168}.$$ To compute $P(U_8 \geq U,E)$, copy the technique above with $$F_u := \{U_8\geq u,U_1 \geq u,U_2 \geq u,U_3 < u,U_4 \geq u, U_5 < u,U_6 \geq u,U_7 \geq u\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$E := \{U_1 \geq U,U_2 \geq U,U_3 < U,U_4 \geq U, U_5 < U,U_6 \geq U,U_7 \geq U\}$

$\Pr(E) = \mathbb{E}(\Pr(E|U))=\mathbb{E}(U^2(1-U)^5)=\dfrac{2!5!}{8!}$

$\Pr(E,U_8\geq U) = \mathbb{E}(\Pr(E,U_8\geq U|U))=\mathbb{E}(U^2(1-U)^6)=\dfrac{2!6!}{9!}$

Therefore, $\Pr(U_8\geq U|E)=\dfrac{\Pr(E,U_8\geq U)}{\Pr(E)}=\dfrac{8!2!6!}{9!2!5!} =\dfrac{2}{3}$

Answer (score -1):

Recall that

$$\mathbb{P}[U \le u] = \max\{\min\{u,1\},0\})$$

Observe that

1. $$\mathbb{P}[\max\{U_3, U_5\} \le u] = (\max\{\min\{u,1\},0\})^2$$
2. $$u = \max\{\min\{u,1\},0\}, u \in [0,1]$$
3. $$\mathbb{P}[\min\{U_1, U_2, U_4, U_6, U_7\} \le u] = 1 - (1 - \mathbb{P}[U_1 \le u])^5$$
4. $$E = \{\max\{U_3, U_5\} < U \le \min\{U_1, U_2, U_4, U_6, U_7\} \}$$

$$ = \{\max\{U_3, U_5\} \color{red}{\le} U \le \min\{U_1, U_2, U_4, U_6, U_7\} \}$$

$$ = \{\max\{U_3, U_5\} \le U \} \cap \{U \le \min\{U_1, U_2, U_4, U_6, U_7\} \}$$

5. $$P(\{\max\{U_3, U_5\} \le U \}) = P(\{\max\{U_3, U_5\} - U \le 0\})$$

$$ = \int_0^1 \int_0^u f_{\max\{U_3, U_5\},U} du_{3,5}du$$

$$ = \int_0^1 \int_0^u f_{\max\{U_3, U_5\}}f_{U} du_{3,5}du$$

$$ = \int_0^1 \int_0^u f_{\max\{U_3, U_5\}}(1) du_{3,5}du$$

$$ = \int_0^1 \int_0^u (2u_{3,5})(1) du_{3,5}du$$

$$= 1/3$$

Or simply note that

$$P(\{\max\{U_3, U_5\} - U \le 0\}) = P(\{\max\{U_3, U_5, U\} = U\})$$

where the RHS is 1/3 by symmetry

6. $$P(\{U \le \min\{U_1, U_2, U_4, U_6, U_7\} \}) = P(\{U = \min\{U, U_1, U_2, U_4, U_6, U_7\} \}) = 1/6$$

Integrate that if you want. :P

7. So how does 4 relate to 5 and 6 in terms of computing $P(E)$?

Comment: "So how does 4 relate to 5 and 6 in terms of computing P(E)?" No. Idea. Whatsoever. (This whole post seems pure spam.)